# Get variable based on a string of the variables name?

Tags: java, variables

I have variable `event` which will contain a string like "playerChatLevel". How can I use that variable to get the value of another variable?

I have `getPermission(Player player, String event)` and within that integers like `int blockPlaceLevel = 0;`.

Comment: are you saying event might also contain "blockPlaceLevel" ? or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: -1 Please add some code so that we know what you're talking about.

Comment: Right. I need to be able to get another variable based on the contents of the first variable.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like what you want is something like a `HashMap<String, Integer>` so your event could be the `String` key and that would map to an `Integer` object.

you can't address another variable directly, but you can use this mapping to achieve basically the same thing.

Comment: Could you please give me an example in a context? I'm very confused :/

Comment: well I don't really know the context of your application, but here is a link with some HashMap examples. http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-hashmap-example.html

Comment: Much too confusing and I dont think that can do what I want. Instead I just used a messier workaround. Thanks anyway.

Comment: ok... don't fear the HashMap, though -- very handy, one of my fave things :-)